# Performance issue in getting nearest location in realtime app

Tags: postgresql, cube, earthdistance

Currently, I'm working on a project like Uber. It means there are two apps: one for driver and one for customer.

The issue is: the driver need to update their location per 2 seconds. And the customer pull all the nearest drivers per 2 seconds for realtime. It cause bad performance in database query. I use cube & earthdistance extension of PostgreSQL for caculating the nearest.

Could anyone show me what's the best way to solve this issue? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you are talking about cars and passengers you need a better solution than just comparing locations. With the PostGIS extension you can load a shapefile of road data and then do network analysis. Not much help if the nearest taxi is across the river or the highway.

Comment: Lots and lots and lots of RAM. You're going to want to fit at least your indexes in RAM. Many CPUs and many fast disks. Also `UNLOGGED` tables for the realtime data. You'll lose it completely in a crash, but since only recent values are of interest that probably doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [deepstream.io](https://deepstream.io/) for realtime data submission, e.g. from Android

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
  // get the record
  Record record = client.record.getRecord( "driver/14" );
  // any kind of data path works
  record.set( "position.x", location.getLongitude() );
  //as well as any kind of serializable datatype
  record.set( "position.y", location.getLatitude() );
}
```

to JavaScript

```
// get the record
var driver = client.record.getRecord( 'driver/14' );

// subscribe to any changes within position
driver.subscribe( 'position', function( position ){
  updateMarker( position.x, position.y );
});
```

Combined with e.g. [RethinkDBs geospacial queries](https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/geo-support/javascript/) which deepstream integrates with this might be a scalable solution.

[Here's an example repo](https://github.com/deepstreamIO/ds-demo-pizza-tracker) demonstrating this